# proper naming convention in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-apps

I am using Django 1.11 and on that I have created an app `country` and inside `country/models.py` I have a model `Country`.

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

and included the model in `admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from country.models import Country

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Country)
```

When I visited `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin`, it shows
[image: admin template]

The spelling of `country` has been pluralized to `Countrys` which is wrong.

**What is proper naming convention to prevent such mistakes?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the spelling mistake , It's `django convention` to show that there will be many records and to show that it adds an `s` at last after the Model Name.

Comment: should not it be `countries`? `Countries` is plural and it represents `will be many records`

Comment: No, django just puts a last `s` after the model name to show it will have many records. It doesn't take care of the things like what if that `s` doesn't make that word plural that is the concern of english language.

Comment: You can use `verbose` to change them to suit what you want but `django` automatically doesn't take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

**PART I** : `Countrys` is your model name, you can set verbosename to define it.

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "country"
        verbose_name_plural = "countries"
```

**PART II**: `COUNTRY` is your app name, in Django 11.1, you can set app name in `apps.py`

```
# in yourapp/apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig

class YourAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'yourapp'
    verbose_name = 'Fancy Title'
```